# java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe while accessing mysql on cloud server

Tags: java, mysql, cloud, network-connection

**Hi . While trying to read from mysql database located on a seperate server on cloud , getting the following error and no data is being returned . I am not able to locate the exact reason for the error . Any suggestions ?? Thanks in advance .**

---

**Steps taken : the time to live for connection is 8 hours and autoreconnect is set to true**

---

```
log4j:WARN Detected problem with connection: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
org.apache.log4j.net.BridgeSocketAppender.append(BridgeSocketAppender.java:264)
org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
 org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
org.apache.log4j.Category.debug(Category.java:260)
com.samsung.svoice.SLogger.debug(SLogger.java:154)
```

Comment: maybe it is caused by your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, this typically happens when the server closes the connection as you're trying to write to it or read from it. Maybe the software you're using is setup incorrectly, since the server thinks it should close the connection while you're still trying to read from it.